# CSS file is not reflecting

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, frontend

I am writing an HTML code and have linked it to an external CSS file. My CSS file was working normally, but suddenly any extra change I make was not reflected to my HTML. I deleted some CSS code to check if anything will change but nothing happened.

For example, I wrote a code to change the background color of my `<body>` tag to blue:

```
body {margin:0px; width:100%;font-family:sans-serif; background:#333; color:#d0d0d0;}
```

When I delete that code then nothing changes and the background is still blue. I have made a research about that problem and some say that this is because Chrome is caching my file.

Could you please advise?

Comment: can you please code ??

Comment: body {margin:0px;
 width:100%;font-family:sans-serif;
 background:#333;
 color:#d0d0d0;}

this code change the background to dark grey, when i delete this code, the background should go back to white, but it still grey. the css file is not reflecting to my page

Comment: probably the parent property still has the color grey, use the developer tool to help you see which causing the grey color

Answer (score 0):

can you paste some code?
or else I don't understand the problem, ill try help as quick as I can!

Comment: body {margin:0px;
 width:100%;font-family:sans-serif;
 background:#333;
 color:#d0d0d0;}

this code change the background to dark grey, when i delete this code, the background should go back to white, but it still grey. the css file is not reflecting to my page

Comment: please post only answers here, comments are for mean for comment section only

Comment: Sorry I hadn't had enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to Browser Caching.
You can use a strategy to bust the cache.

I personally use versioning the Query String Strategy to resolve this issue.

I do it by adding a version number in the linked resource like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=3.4.1">
```

You can change the version number before publishing the website.

For local debugging, you can use `Ctrl + F5`, it'll hard reload the website and request all the resources from the server.